# Python Selenium stuck in loop after form submit

Tags: python, selenium

I have a list of links which I loop through and on each link I update the price field by two percent.

I did a dry-run without the click element at the end and everything worked fine.
When I added the click event on the final row, the new link did not load, it just reloaded the same page and updated the price again by two percent.

```
for link in sprojs_links:
    current_price = 0
    driver.get(link)
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    submit_button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="publish"]')))
    price_input = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="acf-field_5a7c1700c1e4c"]')
    current_price = price_input.get_attribute('value')
    new_price = math.ceil(float(current_price) * 1.02)
    price_input.clear()
    price_input.send_keys(new_price)
    submit_button.click()
```

Any idea what I can do to fix this?

Comment: Does the click() finishes before loading the next link ? you may need to add some wait after submit button click() to see if it goes through first.

Comment: @Sureshmani you're right! I added time.sleep(20) - just to be safe and it worked! Bit slower obviously but works! Thanks